# JSF @ManagedBeans, Dependency Injection, Mocking and Testing

Tags: jsf-2, dependency-injection, servlet-3.0

My setup is a small JSF2.2 application. This application has two `ManagedBean` classes, which both implement the same Interface. One written in Mockito used for development and unit testing (we're using TestNG) and one written in ActiveMQ, used for Production and CI. How do I tell the Facelet which implementation to use? In spring I would use a different application-context, in Guice a different `AbstractModule`. Now before you say use CDI or EJB for this, there's a little catch, for various legacy reasons, beyond my control, or sphere of influence, we're not using a proper JavaEE container (we're using Jetty 9 (upgraded less than 2 months ago from Jetty 6, so yeah).

Now my first reaction would be "Go with what you know", but wiring Guice or Spring Beans into a JSF/PrimeFaces application just feels redundant and wrong.

So my somewhat long-winded question is, is there something I'm overlooking? What is the pure-JSF equivalent of a Spring `@Configuration` or Guice `AbstractModule`? Is Spring/Guice/CDI really a requirement for this?

Comment: Can you post some code? If I understand you correctly you have Mocked objects in your production code?

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of convoluted, I'll see if I van come up with a smaller example that demonstrates the problem. But no I don't have mocked objects in my production code. I have Implementation A for Scenario A, and Implementation B for scenario B, and I'm wondering how I tell the servlet container which is the current scenario.

Comment: Could you use a standard backing for both and use reflection to replace the real implementation for the unit test (provided I understood you correctly).

Comment: Do you use annotations or a faces-config.xml to declare the managed beans?

Comment: Annotations. I suppose I could switch to a file which would probably be the closest to old-style Spring configuration. Hadn't really thought about that.